# Subclassing iOS control - code vs. storyboards

Tags: ios, ios6, uibutton, uistoryboard

Is there any way to subclass an iOS control say a UIButton using storyboards?  I want to make my buttons flat looking, with and without an image, but it seems the storyboarding is limited (tho easy to use) in what it can do?

Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create you custom class and make it a child class of `UIButton` then in Interface builder drag an `UIButton` on your view.

Then in the property inspector go to the third tab and change the class name to match your custom button class.

[image]

Comment: is this the proper way to do it instead of writing code to handle it? I want to control the total look and feel of all the controls, even setting up background layers

Comment: This is a way of doing it, I'm all ways doing it like this, since then there is one place where you change to look and feel of you button, label, ... Or if it is simple styling i'll use the [Appearance Proxy](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: makes sense, it is the way the standard online course said to do, but i was wondering if its good practice to have it all in code without using the storyboard at all?

Comment: i look at apps like Path and Instagram and seems that there entire look and feel has been customized. Just trying to learn best practice.

Comment: Well there is never one way of doing it, since this is very much up to the developers preferences. I would say do it code, save to space on image and it might also make you button more scalable. It's really up to you to find out what you are most convertible with. Going for code if you want to do stuff with `CALayer` is the way to, but sometimes a images is just as good.

Comment: Thanks, plus code seems to make you learn the api a lot better, imo.